# Bootstrap Toggable Tabs with multiple Nav links

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I need a solution for a Bootstrap Toggable Tabs. I am using the Nav-tabs as shown in [Bootstrap Toggable Tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs-examples) here. In my scenario I am triggering the view from multiple locations. The tab content changes but the active links for the two nav-links doesn't change. Can we make the two nav links in sync somehow ?

Here is the JSFiddle with example - https://jsfiddle.net/4n7rg3hy/

```
<div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#home" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" class="active" aria-expanded="false">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#about" id="about-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" role="tab" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show"  role="tabpanel" id="home" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <p>TAB-HOME</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="profile" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      TAB-PROFILE
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade"  role="tabpanel" id="about" aria-labelledby="about-tab">
      <p>TAB-ABOUT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="contact" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
      TAB-CONTACT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
 Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid.
</div>
<div class="bottom-links">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs1" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" class="active" aria-expanded="false">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.nav.nav-tabs a').click(function() {
  var $selector = $('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="' + $(this).attr("href") + '"]').not(this);
  var nav = $selector.closest('.nav.nav-tabs');
  nav.find('a').removeClass("active");
  $selector.addClass("active");
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.nav.nav-tabs a').click(function() {
  var $selector = $('.nav.nav-tabs a[href="' + $(this).attr("href") + '"]').not(this);
  var nav = $selector.closest('.nav.nav-tabs');
  nav.find('a').removeClass("active");
  $selector.addClass("active");
})
```

```css
.bs-example-tabs .nav-tabs li {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.bs-example-tabs .nav-tabs li>a.active {
  background: yellow;
}

.bs-example-tabs .tab-content {
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.bottom-links {
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.bottom-links .nav-tabs li {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.bottom-links .nav-tabs li a.active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#home" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" class="active" aria-expanded="false">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#about" id="about-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" role="tab" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" role="tabpanel" id="home" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
      <p>TAB-HOME</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="profile" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
      TAB-PROFILE
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="about" aria-labelledby="about-tab">
      <p>TAB-ABOUT</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel" id="contact" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
      TAB-CONTACT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  Raw denim you probably haven't heard of them jean shorts Austin. Nesciunt tofu stumptown aliqua, retro synth master cleanse. Mustache cliche tempor, williamsburg carles vegan helvetica. Reprehenderit butcher retro keffiyeh dreamcatcher synth. Cosby sweater
  eu banh mi, qui irure terry richardson ex squid.
</div>
<div class="bottom-links">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs1" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" class="active" aria-expanded="false">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="false">About</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```